# How to make my application access the registry keys independent of whether its 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, 64-bit

I am running a C# Application compiled for AnyCPU. It accesses the registrykeys and gets their value. If the key is not there, it will create it with the default value. I am using the function Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(strRegistryPath) to do this where strRegistryPath is \SOFTWARE\MyAppln. The keys are getting created in HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyAppln on a 32-bit machine and works fine. But when i try to use the same program on a 64-bit machine the keys are getting created in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyAppln. Due to this I am not able to read this values properly.

How to make my program work on both 32-bit and 64-bit machine?

Comment: You are *not* actually compiling your program for AnyCPU.  The name of the Platform doesn't have anything to do with whether or not the jitter is forced to run in 32-bit mode.  The *real* setting that matters is Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.  If you see the "Prefer 32-bit" option then turn it off.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: I am making the platform target as AnyCPU. I can't see any Prefer 32-bit option. Release configuration i didnt get you. Still its not working. @HansPassant

Comment: What is "still not working?" Please define "not working". I'm sure that answer I gave you allows you to write to the 64 bit view from a 32 bit process, if that's what you want. However, one wonders why you are so concerned about writing to the 32 bit view from your 32 bit process. If your process is 32 bit then perhaps the 32 bit view is the right place to write?

Comment: The answer which you gave using _RegistryView_ enum was good actually. But when i started implementing it i realized i cant use **openbasekey** function at all since it is only for .NET 4 and versions above. So i wanted a solution which works on all platforms.I am trying to use *RegOpenKeyEx* currently.

Comment: I used **RegOpenKeyEx** which opens the specified Registry Keyand then **RegQueryValueEx** which retrieves the type and data for the specified value name associated with an open registry key. Also, used  RegSAM.WOW64_32Key as the argument for **RegOpenKeyEx**. So now i am able to access the registry keys for both 32-bit and 64-bit without any problem. Thanks for your replies guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create keys under `HKLM\Software`, then you will be subject to the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). If you want to write the same location irrespective of whether the code is 32 bit or 64 bit you have to pick a single registry view, and always write there. Pick either the 32 bit view, or the 64 bit view, it doesn't really matter.

Once you've made your mind up, use the [`RegistryView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enumeration to force the use of your chosen registry view. Note that on a 32 bit system, there is only one registry view and consequently the value of `RegistryView` that you use is ignored.

For instance, if you open keys using `RegistryView.Registry64` then your keys will never appear under `Wow6432Node`, the 32 bit view under WOW64 redirection. And you can use `RegistryView.Registry64` perfectly well on a 32 bit system where it is just ignored.

You should also know that your program requires elevation since it writes to `HKLM`. That might prove to be an irritation to users.

Comment: I am using **Createsubkey()** function and _Registryview_ enum is used in **openremotebasekey()** function. So how can i do it? Can you please tell how to modify or use that? @David

Comment: Follow the doc link in the answer to the RegistryView enumeration docs. There it tells you to use OpenBaseKey.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target platform. You need to consider how the registry reflection works (s.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384235(v=vs.85).aspx). Beware the behavior was changed in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 (s.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464643(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The reflector was never the answer. Even less so since it was removed a few years ago.